# Adding drop shadow on a menu item box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my first attempt at creating an application, so apologies if my questions are misformed or misplaced.

When you click on 'file' in a menu bar and a little box appears below with options like 'quit' and 'save,' how do I put a drop shadow on this box? I've seriously been tinkering and googling for the longest time with no luck. I feel like I've exhausted the options in visual studio and tried various code in my xaml. Here's the relevant XAML:

```
<Menu x:Name="MenuBar" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="27" Margin="-20,-36,140.4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Foreground="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
    <MenuItem x:Name="File" Header="File" Height="27" Width="39" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated" Foreground="#FF323334" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="1,0,4,4" Padding="6,0">



        <MenuItem x:Name="Save" Header="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="139.2" Click="Save_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Quit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="139.2" Click="MenuItem_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
    </MenuItem>

</Menu>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: I ended up getting my answer [eslewhere](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/efc3fc2a-1994-476d-9129-67eaf2fe3aff/unable-to-add-a-dropshadow-to-a-menuitem-box?forum=wpf)

Comment: Anyone? I've solved so many bugs on my own, but this stupid one is driving me crazy. Way too many hours are going into this. I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, but I can't think of what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create your own `Template`

here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082(v=vs.85).aspx) on how to ovveride the default `MenuItem Style`